# Conditional Independence of Correlated Stochastic Processes

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $\{X_1(t)\}$ and $\{X_2(t)\}$ be discrete-time stochastic processes, such that $X_1(t) = f(I_{t-1},\{Y_{1 t}(I_{t-1})\},\{X_{1 \tau}\}_{\tau \leq t-1} ),$ and $X_2(t) = g(I_{t-1},\{Y_{2 t}(I_{t-1})\},\{X_{1 \tau}\}_{\tau \leq t-1} ),$ where $\{I_t\}$ is an increasing sequence of information vectors, and the $\{Y_{i t}(I_{t-1})\}$ terms are independently distributed random variables which are functions of $I_{t-1}$.

Does it hold that $P(X_1(t) = x_1,X_2(t) = x_2|I_t) = P(X_1(t) = x_1 | I_t) P(X_2(t) = x_2 | I_t)$, i.e. that the distributions of X_1(t) and X_2(t) are conditionally independent, given $I_t.$?

Attempt:
By definition, we have that $$P(X_1(t) = x_1,X_2(t) = x_2|I_t) = P(f(I_{t-1},\{Y_{1 t}(I_{t-1})\},\{X_{1 \tau}\}_{\tau \leq t-1} )= x_1| I_t, X_2(t) = x_2) P(g(I_{t-1},\{Y_{2 t}(I_{t-1})\},\{X_{1 \tau}\}_{\tau \leq t-1} ) = x_2|I_t).$$

I am tempted to say that since $f$ does not depend on $X_2(t),$ it follows that $P(X_1(t) = x_1| I_t, X_2(t) = x_2) = P(X_1(t) = x_1| I_t),$ but this argument leaves a very deep, sinking feeling that it lacks both rigor and understanding.  It just ``seems right,'' that since the $X_1$ and $X_2$ are only coupled through $I_t,$ they ought to be independent if $I_t$ is known.

Context: 
I'm analyzing a discrete-time stochastic process with many (i.e. much more than two) random variables which affect each other stochastically, but only through quantities which I can observe at each time instant.  Heuristically, it would ``make sense,'' for these variables to be conditionally independent, given the observations specified (as above), but I am have a doozy of a time proving it through first principles.  In other words, the process dynamics are a bit too complex to verify the product identity directly.

So, if the above question is too ill posed, I would also appreciate pointers to alternate means of verifying conditional independence.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: What is meant by $P[X_1(t)|I_t]$?  How can you take the probability of random variable?  You can only take probabilities of events.  Do you mean $P[X_1(t)\leq x_1 | I_t]$?

Comment: Yes, sorry!  Mixed the shorthand I was using while working on the actual problem I'm studying with what I was writing while posting.  Will edit to fix now!

Comment: If your information vector gives you no information, then your conjecture reduces to the (false) claim that any two discrete random variables are independent.

Comment: Or, if you prefer, just consider the case $X_1(t)=X_2(t)$ for all $t$.

Comment: Yes, I suppose I need to consider the structure of the information vector more explicitly.  It is not empty, and in particular contains the values of many samples of the past random variables.

I think the case in which $X_1(t) = X_2(t)$ is excluded by my restriction that neither $X_1(\tau)$ nor $X_2(\tau)$ are included in $I_t$ for any $\tau,$ but I appreciate the reply.  It is obvious there are trivial cases for general processes in which this won't work, and I need to consider the structure of my problem more carefully.

Comment: Edited for clarity; in particular, the structures of the information vector and the processes were made more explicit.